# ASP.Net MVC Entity Framework Not Outputting Values for Model with empty list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an ASP.Net MVC application using Entity Framework and having an issue trying to display values from my model.

I have the following Model for a class called Bill which has a list of BillSubjects within it

```
    [Table("bill")]
    public partial class Bill
    {
    [Key]
    public int BillId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Bill Number")]
    public string BillNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BillId")]
    public virtual List<BillSubject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

and the following definition for BillSubject:

```
[Table("billSubject")]
public partial class BillSubject
{
    [Key]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public int BillId { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

Code used to retrieve data upon a user clicking on the a specific bill: I have put a breakpoint on this code and never see any issues with the code in either scenario.

```
        public ActionResult Bill(int billid)
        {
            Bill bill = db.bill.Find(billid);
            if(bill == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View("~/Views/Bill/Bill.cshtml", bill);
        }
```

Some bills won't have subjects and when i use the entity framework it creates an empty list within the object which should be fine. 
When i load this page for a bill which has subjects stored in my database everything populates fine, the Bill title item and the Subject Count one. 
But when i try with a Bill that does not have any subjects then everything will be rendered empty. I viewed the source in by browser and the Title tag is just the h3 tags, no text within.

Any thoughts on what i need to change for this?

Bill View:

```
@model RepresentWebApp.Models.Bill
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Bill";
}

<h2>Bill</h2>
<h3>@Html.DisplayName(Model.Title)</h3>
<h3>@Html.DisplayName(Model.Subjects.Count())</h3>
```

Full HTML when I load the Page  (includes my page header, basically the ASP.Net default):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bill - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
            </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a></li>
</ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">



<h2>Bill</h2>
<h3></h3>
<h3>0</h3>






    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2017 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>



<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"410cd4ef6a3c4f1a8a11ad3bd6972ab3"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://localhost:50287/130502d9b020420c9a2ea324e4312c38/browserLink" 
async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

HTML for a Bill with a Subject that will Load the Bills title:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Bill - My ASP.NET Application</title>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a></li>
</ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">



<h2>Bill</h2>
<h3>A bill to award career pathways innovation grants to local educational agencies and consortia of local educational agencies, to provide technical assistance within the Office of Career, Technical, and Adult Education to administer the grants and support t</h3>
<h3>1</h3>






    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2017 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>



<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
{"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"cf9f70c608384cdb941887f9887ca6c2"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:50287/130502d9b020420c9a2ea324e4312c38/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: arnt u missing a ")" in the last line of your code?

Comment: can you also please post the final html your are getting in the browser?

Comment: Can you post the code that is retrieving the data?

Comment: @ParvSharma Fixed my HTML, and now the count seems to appear correctly whether there are subjects in the list or not as can be seen in the HTML from the page. Now i'm almost more confused. When debugging the code title doesn't seem to be null/empty upon being passed to the page.   Also added the code that my ActionResult function which loads this page and gets the data based on a billid.

Answer (score 0):

> But when i try with a Bill that does not have any subjects then everything will be rendered empty. I viewed the source in by browser and the Title tag is just the h3 tags, no text within.

If you don't want to display the  markup at all

`@if(Model.Subjects.Count != 0)
{
//markup here
}`

Similarly if you don't want to display the count when they don't exist in Model then:
`@if(Model.Subjects.Count() != 0) @Model.Subjects.Count()`
This will show the value

If you want to display to name of the field
`@Html.DisplayNameFor(a=>a.Title);`
This will show the Name and not the content of the field

If you want the content of the field in the Model `@Html.DisplayName(Model.Subjects);`
This will show the content of the field `@Model.Subjects` will do the same.

To show Subject in `List<Subjects>` you need to iterate through the list

```
`@{
    if (Model.Subject != Null) {
        foreach (var item in Model.Subjects){
            <h3> @item.Subject <h3>
        }
    }
}`
```